# How can I join conditionally in LINQ queries?

Tags: linq, join, conditional-statements

If I have two tables; Drivers keyed by DriverId and Trips with foreign keys DriverId and CoDriverId, and I want to find all trips where a driver was either the driver or co-driver I could code this in Transact-SQL as

```
select d.DriverId, t.TripId 
from Trips t inner join Drivers d 
on t.DriverId = d.DriverId or t.CoDriverId = d.DriverId
```

How could this be coded as a LINQ query?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't do it with a LINQ join, basically - LINQ only directly supports equijoins.

You *can* however do:

```
var query = from trip in db.Trips
            from driver in db.Drivers
            where trip.DriverId == driver.DriverId ||
                  trip.CoDriverId == driver.DriverId
            select new { driver.DriverId, trip.TripId };
```

That may well end up with the same join in the converted SQL.

Comment: Basically like the old SQL syntax before we began using JOIN keywords then.